# Placing element on top of something

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is tricky, I'm using Dynatables to generate this table, and the search bar is included with this, so I have no access to the HTML and placement of it.

I have a **Select Season** drop down, and I need it to be above it. On mobile, they are going to be 100% width.

http://sim.rgmgleague.com/stats2/?season=current

[image: elements]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: try `.top { margin-bottom: 16px; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `clear: both` to `.dynatable-search`?

```
.dynatable-search{
  clear:both
}
```

Seems to work for me